# submit form after confirmation by jquery dialog for payment

Tags: jquery, dialog, submit, payment-gateway

I have a  book now submit button for payment gateway.

The dialog box is not staying its submitting the form without confirming.

How to stop submitting form.

Here is code :

```
var submitForm = $('#paypal');
submit = false;

$("#confirm").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height: 140,
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: {
        'Submit': function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            submit = true;
            submitForm.submit();
        },
        'Cancel': function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});
$("#confirm").parent().appendTo($("#paypal")); 

submitForm.submit(function() {
    if (submit) {
        return true;
    } else {
        $("#confirm").dialog('open');
        return false;
    }
});
```

HTML code hidden values are removed:

```
<form id="paypal" name="paypal" method='post' action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
<input type="submit" class="book_nowinp" value="book_now" name="btnBook"/>
         </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use submit button in your form, use a normal button instead and open the confirm dialog onclick of that button.

```
<input type="button" class="book_nowinp" onclick="$('#confirm').dialog('open')" value="book_now" name="btnBook"/>
```

You already have the code to trigger form submit on the `onclick` event of submit button of the dialog, so now just remove the handler on form submit.